# Use the definition of limit of a function to find the limit of $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0, 0)} \frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2}=0$

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations

Use the definition of limit of a function to find the limit of $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0, 0)} \frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2}=0$.

I am not sure even how to start. I believe it wants me to use the delta-epsilon definition since that is the definition the section was over. So, $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0, 0)} \frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2}=0$ if given any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x,y)-0|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Probably you can find some duplicate on that.

Comment: We have $0\leq x^4+y^4\leq (x^2+y^2)^2$.

Comment: @user Indeed.${}$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Probably many users are not aware how to search and find previous questions by themselves.

Comment: Why did you use the [tag:partial-differential-equations] tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Observe that $x^4 + y^4 \le (x^2+y^2)^2$. So $\frac{x^4+y^4}{x^2+y^2} \le x^2+y^2$.

Now try to use $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

On one hand, we have that
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{4}}{x^{2} + y^{2}} = x^{2}\left(\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\right)
\end{align*}

On the other hand, the relation holds:
\begin{align*}
0\leq x^{2} \leq x^{2} + y^{2} \Rightarrow 0\leq \frac{x^{2}}{x^{2} + y^{2}}\leq 1
\end{align*}

Consequently, it results that
\begin{align*}
0\leq \frac{x^{4}}{x^{2} + y^{2}} \leq x^{2}
\end{align*}

Then you can apply the squeeze theorem.

The same approach works for the remaining expression.

Can you take it from here?